# Filtering a joined column in Kartik Grid in Yii2

Tags: yii2

When I'm Filtering a column of a table, it works fine. Please tell me how to search a joined column. In the following screenshot Manager is a joined column. Manager is alias for parties.name_manager. It's same for both the parent and child view. I am using Kartik Grid.
[image: Kartik Grid]

Here is my index.php for the parent

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use backend\modules\managerproductsalesmonthly\models\ProductsalesdetailsSearch;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel backend\modules\managerproductsalesmonthly\models\ProductsalesSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Productsales';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="productsales-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <!-- <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Productsales', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p> -->

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'export' => false,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
                'value' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
                return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
            },
                'detail' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
                $searchModel = new ProductsalesdetailsSearch();               
                $searchModel-> productname = $model->productname;
                //$searchModel-> total = $model->total;
                $searchModel-> manager = $model->manager;
                $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

                return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_productsales', [
                    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    ]);                   

                },
            ],
            //['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            // 'id',
            // 'productsales_ebillid',
            // 'year',
            // 'console',
            // 'billno:ntext',
            [
             'attribute' => 'manager',
             'value' => 'productsalesPartyname.name_manager'
            ],
            //'billdate',
            // 'productsales_partyname',
            // 'itemid',
            'productname',
            // 'batchno',
            // 'expdate',
            // 'mrp',
            // 'rate',
            // 'productiondate',
            // 'prodqty',
            // 'qty',
            // 'free',
            'total',
            // 'discount',

            //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean for joined column ...is a column related to an external table/class and you want filter the gridview also with this related field when you input a value in the corresponding input filter ? .. or somethings other.. ?

Comment: I  don't understand please confirm .. is a column related to external column?

Comment: The manager column comes from parties table. It is joined with productsales table. It is a related column as parties.partyname = productsales.partyname. I want to pass this manager from the parent grid to the child grid like the product.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this guide earlier

http://www.ramirezcobos.com/2014/04/16/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview-yii2/

Hope it helps

Comment: This is a wonderful link. I've done this. But this is not the solution I want. I want to pass the joined column value from the parent grid to the child grid when I click on the expand button in the left of the grid.